# Deploying RESTful service to AWS with Spring boot

Tags: java, rest, maven, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I am trying to deploy a simple Spring Boot RESTful service to AWS beanstalk. I am using mvn clean package to get the war. This is my code:

```
 //@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}

package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
}

@RequestMapping("/hello/{name}")
String hello(@PathVariable String name) {
    return "Hello, " + name + "!";
}
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-rest-service</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <tomcat.version>8.0.3</tomcat.version>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

But when I try to access (load-balancer-url)/hello/World I get a 404 error. Any help on what I am doing wrong? thank you.

Comment: This application working correct on your local environments?

Comment: Yes it works, but I get rid of the war packagin and tomcat property.  I deploy it like this: java -jar target/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar, and I can access it at http://localhost:8080/hello/World.

Comment: your aws url is with 8080 port ?

Comment: No, when I deploy the jar on my local host it works. When I package it as war and deploy it in Beanstalk I get a 404 error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Spring Boot | Create a deployable war file](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file)

From the docs:

> The first step in producing a deployable war file is to provide a
>   SpringBootServletInitializer subclass and override its configure
>   method. This makes use of Spring Framework’s Servlet 3.0 support and
>   allows you to configure your application when it’s launched by the
>   servlet container. Typically, you update your application’s main class
>   to extend SpringBootServletInitializer:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: I added the method and it works like a charm. Million thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can install it using ElasticBeanstalk as well. 
First you need war file. Go to the application folder and do the packaging with Maven as follow.

```
mvn package -DskipTests
```

(In windows machines, duplicate the mvnw.cmd and name the copy as mvnw.bat)

Upon successful packaging task, you will find yourprojectname-snapshot.war in 'target' folder.

After uploading the war file to the Beanstalk, click **Configure more options**
and go to the **Software** section and just need to set SERVER_PORT to 5000 as shown below. After being set, click **Create Environment**.

[image]